# How to manager Fragment like ActivityGroup manager Activity

Tags: android

As we know, ActivityGroup is deprecated.I'm try to reconfigure my code.

this code use ActivityGroup :

```
public void lauchContentActivity(Intnet intent) {
    View view = getLocationActivityManager().startActivity(
            intent.getComponent().getShortClassName(),
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP))
            .getDecorView();
    setContentView(view);
}
```

So I can toogle any activity's visible ,and save the activity instance state which is hide.

But FragmentManager has only a backstack, and can't bring a fragment to front expect pressing the Back button.

How to manager Fragment like ActivityGroup manager Activity?

Comment: Reading your question, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve.  Can you give some details about your use case?  What the user would be doing, and how your app reacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved fragment tabs, Its was challenging for me to achieve and to understand fragment hierarchy while adding and removing fragment.

As the question of managing `fragments`, its depend on your requirement, *[this](https://codeload.github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy/zip/master) sample details you hierarchy of fragments & way to manage fragment with the help of HashMap.*

Below class will explain you behaviorof fragment. (class present in that sample)

*AppMainTabActivity.java*

```
public class AppMainTabActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /* Your Tab host */
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    /* A HashMap of stacks, where we use tab identifier as keys.. */
    private HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;

    /* Save current tabs identifier in this.. */
    private String mCurrentTab;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_main_tab_fragment_layout);

        /*
         * Navigation stacks for each tab gets created.. tab identifier is used
         * as key to get respective stack for each tab
         */
        mStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>();
        mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_A, new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_B, new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_C, new Stack<Fragment>());

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(listener);
        mTabHost.setup();

        initializeTabs();
    }

    private View createTabView(final int id) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_icon, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));
        return view;
    }

    public void initializeTabs() {
        /* Setup your tab icons and content views.. Nothing special in this.. */
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAB_A);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(-3);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });

        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.toolkittabicon));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAB_B);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.followtabicon));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);

        spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAB_C);
        spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return findViewById(R.id.realtabcontent);
            }
        });
        spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.myhuddletabicion));
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    /* Comes here when user switch tab, or we do programmatically */
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener listener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            /* Set current tab.. */
            mCurrentTab = tabId;

            if (mStacks.get(tabId).size() == 0) {
                /*
                 * First time this tab is selected. So add first fragment of
                 * that tab. Dont need animation, so that argument is false. We
                 * are adding a new fragment which is not present in stack. So
                 * add to stack is true.
                 */
                if (tabId.equals(AppConstants.TAB_A)) {
                    pushFragments(tabId, new ToolKitFragment(), false, true);
                } else if (tabId.equals(AppConstants.TAB_B)) {
                    pushFragments(tabId, new FollowFragment(), false, true);
                } else if (tabId.equals(AppConstants.TAB_C)) {
                    pushFragments(tabId, new HuddleFragment(), false, true);
                }
            } else {
                /*
                 * We are switching tabs, and target tab is already has atleast
                 * one fragment. No need of animation, no need of stack pushing.
                 * Just show the target fragment
                 */
                pushFragments(tabId, mStacks.get(tabId).lastElement(), false,
                        false);
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * Might be useful if we want to switch tab programmatically, from inside
     * any of the fragment.
     */
    public void setCurrentTab(int val) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(val);
    }

    /*
     * To add fragment to a tab. tag -> Tab identifier fragment -> Fragment to
     * show, in tab identified by tag shouldAnimate -> should animate
     * transaction. false when we switch tabs, or adding first fragment to a tab
     * true when when we are pushing more fragment into navigation stack.
     * shouldAdd -> Should add to fragment navigation stack (mStacks.get(tag)).
     * false when we are switching tabs (except for the first time) true in all
     * other cases.
     */
    public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment,
            boolean shouldAnimate, boolean shouldAdd) {
        if (shouldAdd)
            mStacks.get(tag).push(fragment);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        if (shouldAnimate)
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void popFragments() {
        /*
         * Select the second last fragment in current tab's stack.. which will
         * be shown after the fragment transaction given below
         */
        Fragment fragment = mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).elementAt(
                mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() - 2);

        /* pop current fragment from stack.. */
        mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).pop();

        /*
         * We have the target fragment in hand.. Just show it.. Show a standard
         * navigation animation
         */
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (((BaseFragment) mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).lastElement())
                .onBackPressed() == false) {
            Log.d("######", "on back press");
            /*
             * top fragment in current tab doesn't handles back press, we can do
             * our thing, which is
             * 
             * if current tab has only one fragment in stack, ie first fragment
             * is showing for this tab. finish the activity else pop to previous
             * fragment in stack for the same tab
             */
            if (mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() == 1) {
                super.onBackPressed(); // or call finish..
            } else {
                popFragments();
            }
        } else {
            // do nothing.. fragment already handled back button press.
        }
    }

    /*
     * Imagine if you wanted to get an image selected using ImagePicker intent
     * to the fragment. Ofcourse I could have created a public function in that
     * fragment, and called it from the activity. But couldn't resist myself.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        /* Now current fragment on screen gets onActivityResult callback.. */
        mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).lastElement()
                .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

But if you have child fragment then it will create issue on back press which is not handle in that sample, solution@ you have to *Override onDetach()* method and manage child fragment check below code snippet.

```
@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
         try {
                Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
                childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
                childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    }
```

Additionally refer developer site and dig [fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) in details.

Comment: I am not sure that tabs is what the OP wants to use `Fragment`s for.

Answer (score 2):

The feasibility of this answer will depend on what you want to accomplish with the different activities. I had a similar problem and I solved it by using `Fragment`s. Imagine that you have one `Activity` for your task which has different facets. Then you can easily use the `Activity` to gather and persist data that you will need in each `Fragment` or to feed your business logic and your `Fragment`s can each cater to different facets of the task. I would highly recommend this as `Fragment`and `FragmentManager`are supposed to replace the deprecated `ActivityGroup`. Here is some documentation on the matter:

- [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)
- [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Now, using `Fragment`s is a bit different from using `Activity` but not to much. Basically, you declare your `Fragment`like any other object. To show your `Fragment`  you will use:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerID, yourFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack();
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The documentation that you can download using ADK also contains a lot of samples that use `Fragment`s. I believe it is a good start if you want to get some quality code snippets!